# Windows network folder from Docker Linux Container

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following situation:

I have a windows network folder that must be accessed from a net-core linux container image (**microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0**)

How can I achieve this? I couldn't find much info on docker volumes.

This is my dockercompose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  acesso.bankreturn.service:
    image: acesso.bankreturn.service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Acesso.BankReturn.Service/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
      - elk
    secrets:
      - BankReturnConnectionString
      - DiItauCron
      - DiItauDepositTypes
      - DiItauErrorPath
      - DiItauInputPath
      - DiItauProcessingPath
      - DiItauSuccessPath
      - DiItauTemporaryPath
      - ElkConnectionString
      - ElkResourceName
      - EmailSender
      - EmailSenderName
      - EmailSubject
      - EmailToAddress
      - RabbitHostName
      - RabbitPassword
      - RabbitQueue
      - RabbitUserName
  db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    environment:
      - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"
      - "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=VcDERqwfaDs4bkEHDJ1H"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
  elk:
    image: sebp/elk:564
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
      - "9200:9200"
      - "5044:5044"
secrets:
  BankReturnConnectionString:
    file: ./secrets/BankReturnConnectionString.txt
  DiItauCron:
    file: ./secrets/DiItauCron.txt
  DiItauDepositTypes:
    file: ./secrets/DiItauDepositTypes.txt
  DiItauErrorPath:
    file: ./secrets/DiItauErrorPath.txt
  DiItauInputPath:
    file: ./secrets/DiItauInputPath.txt
  DiItauProcessingPath:
    file: ./secrets/DiItauProcessingPath.txt
  DiItauSuccessPath:
    file: ./secrets/DiItauSuccessPath.txt
  DiItauTemporaryPath:
    file: ./secrets/DiItauTemporaryPath.txt
  ElkConnectionString:
    file: ./secrets/ElkConnectionString.txt
  ElkResourceName:
    file: ./secrets/ElkResourceName.txt
  EmailSender:
    file: ./secrets/EmailSender.txt
  EmailSenderName:
    file: ./secrets/EmailSenderName.txt
  EmailSubject:
    file: ./secrets/EmailSubject.txt
  EmailToAddress:
    file: ./secrets/EmailToAddress.txt
  RabbitHostName:
    file: ./secrets/RabbitHostName.txt
  RabbitPassword:
    file: ./secrets/RabbitPassword.txt
  RabbitQueue:
    file: ./secrets/RabbitQueue.txt
  RabbitUserName:
    file: ./secrets/RabbitUserName.txt
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY Acesso.BankReturn.Service/Acesso.BankReturn.Service.csproj Acesso.BankReturn.Service/
COPY Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Service.Logger/Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Service.Logger.csproj Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Service.Logger/
COPY Acesso.BankReturn.Domain/Acesso.BankReturn.Domain.csproj Acesso.BankReturn.Domain/
COPY Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Data/Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Data.csproj Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Data/
COPY Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Service.Queue/Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Service.Queue.csproj Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Service.Queue/
COPY Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.CrossCutting.DTOs/Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.CrossCutting.DTOs.csproj Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.CrossCutting.DTOs/
COPY Acesso.BankReturn.Application/Acesso.BankReturn.Application.csproj Acesso.BankReturn.Application/
COPY Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Service.Notificator/Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Service.Notificator.csproj Acesso.BankReturn.Infra.Service.Notificator/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Acesso.BankReturn.Service
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Acesso.BankReturn.Service.dll"]
```

Do you have a implementation example?
Thanks.